# Can't select anything in the Input Method tab

Tags: kubuntu, kde, ibus

[image]

As you can see in the image, I can't select anything. What should I do? I use Kubuntu 13.10, KDE 4.12.3 and want to use ibus-bogo as my Vietnamese input. My command to install ibus is:

```
sudo apt-get install ibus ibus-qt4 ibus-bogo libibus-qt1 gir1.2-ibus-1.0 ibus-gtk ibus-gtk3 libibus-1.0-5 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 language-pack-vi language-pack-gnome-vi
```

I have installed ibus-m17n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug causes by oxygen-gtk theme. Changing it will make it works again. Go to System Settings → Application Appearence → GTK → change the GTK3 theme to whatever you like.